# Issue while converting linq result to JSON in MVC4 using JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, json, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

Im trying to convert linq result to JSON using JavaScriptSerializer but i didn get the desired output.

My Code is(im using C#):

```
string Departments = "";
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Departments =  jss.Serialize(db.Departments.ToList());
ViewBag.Department = Departments;
```

what i get is:

```
[{"DepartmentId":2,"DepartmentName":"Cardiology","EntityState":2,"EntityKey":{"EntitySetName":"Departments","EntityContainerName":"ClinicDbEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"DepartmentId","Value":2}],"IsTemporary":false}},{"DepartmentId":6,"DepartmentName":"ENT","EntityState":2,"EntityKey":{"EntitySetName":"Departments","EntityContainerName":"ClinicDbEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"DepartmentId","Value":6}],"IsTemporary":false}},{"DepartmentId":7,"DepartmentName":"Paediatrics","EntityState":2,"EntityKey":{"EntitySetName":"Departments","EntityContainerName":"ClinicDbEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"DepartmentId","Value":7}],"IsTemporary":false}},{"DepartmentId":8,"DepartmentName":"General","EntityState":2,"EntityKey":{"EntitySetName":"Departments","EntityContainerName":"ClinicDbEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"DepartmentId","Value":8}],"IsTemporary":false}}]
```

what i needed is like this:

```
[ { DepartmentId: 2, DepartmentName: "Cardiology" }, { DepartmentId: 6, DepartmentName: "ENT" },{ DepartmentId: 7, DepartmentName: "Paediatrics" },{ DepartmentId: 8, DepartmentName: "General"}]
```

can somebody help me please.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Departments= jss.Serialize(
              db.Departments.Select(d => new{
                    DepartmentId = d.DepartmentId,
                    DepartmentName = d.DepartmentName
                })
            );
```